# debug read/write string to binary file

Tags: c++, debugging, file-io, binary, binaryfiles

I am trying to write to a binary file , here is my snippet of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct user
{
    string ID;
    string password;    
};

int main()
{
    fstream afile;
    afile.open("user.dat",ios::out|ios::binary);

    user person;

    person.ID ="001";

    person.password ="abc";

    afile.write (reinterpret_cast <const char *>(&person), sizeof (person));

    person.ID ="002";

    person.password ="def";

    afile.write (reinterpret_cast <const char *>(&person), sizeof (person));

    afile.close();

    afile.open("user.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);


    while (afile.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&person), sizeof (person)))
    {
        cout<<person.ID
            <<" "
            <<person.password
            <<endl;

    }

}
```

I am expecting my console output to be

```
001 abc
002 def
```

Instead i am getting

```
002 def 
002 def
```

Can someone explain to me?

Comment: it's always a good idea to close a file after you are done with it, like the second time you open `afile`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly, The destructor closes it.

Comment: This won't work. A `std::string` is not a plain old data object and you can't dump them to/from a file this way. Look into __serialization__ instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531797/getting-garbage-values-while-reading-struct-data-from-a-binary-file/19532502#19532502

Comment: Do note that `std::string` has a pointer internally and you're writing and reading that pointer, not the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::string is a class and the object of it doesn't store the content of the string directly.

It's implementation defined by for your case, for simplicity, you can understand it this way:

std::string has a member that stores the pointer(say ptr) to the actual data.

and

```
   std::string s = "001";
```

would not point ptr to the address string of "001"; it would allocate memory and copy the string into that memory.
Then when you do

```
    s = "002";
```

it doesn't need to reallocate memory to store "002"; it just copy "002" to the memory that stores "001" previously.

This means, if you dump the raw data of the string, it does NOT change.

When you read back the string raw data, it would just restore the *pointer* that points to "002".

hope this helps.

Comment: please say how can fix it .

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot do it so simply thus you are writing only a pointer to std::string and not what string contains. You could write string to binary file this way:

```
afile.open("user.dat",ios::out|ios::binary);

user person;

person.ID ="001";
person.password ="abc";

int len = person.ID.size();
afile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof(len));
afile.write(const_cast<char*>(person.ID.c_str()), len);

len = person.password.size();
afile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof(len));
afile.write(const_cast<char*>(person.password.c_str()), len);

person.ID ="002";
person.password ="def";

afile.close();
```

And that way you could read

```
afile.open("user.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);

afile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof(len));
person.ID.resize(len);
afile.read(const_cast<char*>(person.ID.c_str()), len);

afile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof(len));
person.password.resize(len);
afile.read(const_cast<char*>(person.password.c_str()), len);

cout << person.ID << " " << person.password << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the raw data of a `struct` that, in fact, contains only pointers. That’s the way `std::string` uses for storing data in order to make the string resizeable. The only reason your program *does* print any data is that in the moment of reading, the object `person` still exists.  If you put the reading part of your program into a separate program, you won’t be able to read any data.

To actually store your data using `fstream`, you can store one string per line, for example:

```
afile << person.ID << endl;
afile << person.password << endl;
```

The file `user.dat`:

```
001
abc
002
def
```

And you can read it this way:

```
afile >> person.ID >> person.password;
while (afile.good())
{
  cout<<person.ID
  <<" "
  <<person.password
  <<endl;
  afile >> person.ID >> person.password;    
}
```

You should also check [Serializing a class which contains a std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046244/serializing-a-class-which-contains-a-stdstring).